# generic callback function with xmlhttp how to send the reference to a function when "this" changes

Tags: javascript, callback, xmlhttprequest, this

I am polling a database.
see the "<--------------" in the code below.

This works:

```
class MultiplayerGame{
...

...
callPhpWithAjax(url){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var instance = this;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            instance.pollResponse(this.responseText); <-----------works, pollResponse is called and I can access the object with "this"
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

poll(){
    var url = "myurl.com"
    this.callPhpWithAjax(url);
}

pollResponse(response){
    this.variable = response;
}
```

}

When I try to implement it a bit more generic, it doesn't work:

```
class MultiplayerGame{
...
callPhpWithAjaxGenericNOTWORKING(url,callbackfunction){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            callbackfunction(this.responseText); <----------callbackfunction not calling what I wanted.
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

poll(){
    var url = "myurl.com"
    this.callPhpWithAjaxGenericNOTWORKING(url, this.pollResponse);  <---------------  it seems like this.pollResponse is not ok. I don't know how to do it.
}

pollResponse(response){
    this.variable = response;  <----- this.variable is undefined. (this is not the class instance i was hoping) 
}
```

When I call the function with the callbackfunction, I use "this", but apparently, it does not reference the same object. I am confused here.

How do I send the callbackfunction correctly as a paramenter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.bind(this)` when using an object's method as a callback parameter.

So your code inside `poll` should be

```
this.callPhpWithAjaxGenericNOTWORKING(url, this.pollResponse.bind(this))
```

---

See [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: time to really wrap my head around this. Thanks!